# Design pattern for different kind of input messages

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a service which can receive input messages in different formats like json, xml, csv etc. Though messages are in different format but data is similar in all of them. Which design pattern should i use to achieve following:

- Should be able to add new message format without changing existing code.
- Convert different message formats into a uniform format to be consumed by core service for processing.

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: it sounds for me as you need to use different `Strategy` for different message format. hence you should use strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, I would say the Strategy pattern.

Make an abstract class (e.g. InputMessage), and derive strategies for json, xml etc. For a new type of input messages, only a new strategy can be derived from InputMessage.

You can use operations for converting to/from the generic format (these will differ for each strategy).

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution is Visitor pattern. There are lot of references that explain what is this, so I will not replicate them.

Pros:
 -  compile time validation. Once you add new format you "must" provide its implementation.

Contras:
 - All implementations are done in one class, e.g. `ProcessorVisitor`. At least it is a kind of entry point to processing of all types of messages. 
 - Message must implement interface `Visitable` that you have to define, so message "knows" that it is going to be visited.

Other solution is just create interface `Processor` with several implementations, e.g. `XmlProcessor`, `JsonProcessor` etc. Create `ProcessorFactory` that creates factory according to the message format. This factory may be either hard coded or based on some metadata, e.g. properties file that maps format to factory implementation. It may be even based on naming convention, e.g. `json` is mapped to `JsonProcessor` etc or on annotations.

Comment: My understanding of Visitor pattern assumes a composite data structure (for `Visitable`). We want to avoid having to modify that code to add the part that varies. What is the analog of that structure in the OP's problem? He only mentions messages of different formats, but there's no relationship between them. Visitor seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, this is the reason that I suggested second solution that is IMHO better.